# Translating diagram to SQL Database

Tags: sql, database, diagram

I'm having trouble seeing how I should translate this diagram into my database with tables. I'd like to add that I'm very new to this. This is a picture of an example that I want to translate into my SQL Database:

[image: Diagram]

I'm not really sure how a diagram like this could look in my SQL Database, haven't really worked with inheritance. Would really appreciate if someone could demostrate how this could look with tables in SQL.

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
create table Person(
IDCode CHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
primary key (IDCode),
);

create table Student(
IDCode CHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(15),
Course VARCHAR(15)
primary key (Name),
foreign key (IDCode) references Person (IDCode)
);

create table Teacher(
IDCode CHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(15),
Course VARCHAR(15)
primary key (Name),
foreign key (IDCode) references Person (IDCode)
);

create table StudentTeacherRelationship(
StudentName VARCHAR(15),
TeacherName VARCHAR(15),
primary key(StudentName,TeacherName),
foreign key(StudentName) references Student (Name),
foreign key(TeacherName) references Teacher (Name),
```

Answer (score 2):

It means:

- a person has a id number
- both students and teachers are persons and they have their id information in person table, and one student/teacher has only one id
- a student can have many teachers
- a teacher can teach to many students

so there should be 4 tables(just psudo pseudo code to give you an idea):

person table:
id_person, (the primary key)
real_id (the real id, can be anything)

student table:
id_student,
id_person,
name,
other_stuff

teacher table:
id_teacher
id_person,
name,
other_stuff

a techer_student table (which make it many to many)
id_student
id_teacher

Comment: I just dont recomend use name as primary key, because many people have same full name. and like h3nr1x said, this is only one of 3 approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to deal with inheritance situation in databases, [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API), for example, defines 3 strategies for inheritance in databases, these are: Single Table, Table for Class and Joined, they are all best described (including table/class examples) in the following [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance)